# Open RSS feed link from uitableviewcell in safari instead of a new viewcontroller

Tags: iphone, xcode, rss, feed

I am using this http://imthi.com/blog/programming/iphone-rss-reader-application-with-source-code.php as a start for my rss reader in my app for loading news. I am trying to get it when you select a cell row it opens the link in safari instead of another viewcontroller. I am still learning how to develop for iPhone. This is what opens the new view which I want to open in safari, it is probably simple but since Im new to this I can't figure it out.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[[self appDelegate] setCurrentlySelectedBlogItem:[[[self rssParser]rssItems]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
[self.appDelegate loadNewsDetails];
```

}

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"THE RSS URL"]];

Comment: ok that helps now I got this:                                       - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    NSString * linkUrl = [[[self appDelegate]currentlySelectedBlogItem]linkUrl];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:linkUrl];
}    It just gives me Expected ']' before ';' token at the openurl line.

Comment: Ok I got that error fixed (stupid mistake) now it just doesn't do anything when you click on a cell.

Comment: add some code? the question has been answered... but there must be some error in your code

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the code. After realizing I missed a part of it I got it to work.